# Rxjs how this syntax is valid?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Hello in Rxjs documentation I see this code:

```
first()(of(1, 2, 3)).subscribe((v) => console.log(`value: ${v}`));

// Logs:
// value: 1
```

I knew it's like Just as `[1, 2, 3].map(x => x * x)` , but I would know if we can do the same with native JavaScript if so please give me an example ?

my question is :

I don't understand how first()(of(1, 2, 3)) can you explain me how this code return an observable with an operator and source ? I knew operator is the first() and source is of() but how they're merged together inside a new observable ?

Thank you

Comment: That is pure JavaScript. What is your question exactly?

Comment: I don't understand how first()(of(1, 2, 3)) can you explain me how this code return an observable with an operator and source ? I knew operator is the first() and source is of() but how they're merged together inside a new observable ?

Answer (score 4):

Executing `first()` returns a function which takes an observable and returns an observable.

Let's break down that line of code so maybe it's easier to understand.

```
first()(of(1, 2, 3)).subscribe((v) => console.log(`value: ${v}`));
```

The following code is equivalent to the above line:

```
const myFunction = first();
const source$ = of(1, 2, 3);

const output$ = myFunction(source$);

output$.subscribe(v => console.log(`value: ${v}`));  // value: 1
```

So, `myFunction` is a function, specifically an [`OperatorFunction`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/types.ts#L8) that essentially looks like this:

```
function myFunction(source: Observable): Observable { }
```

> How they're merged together inside a new observable?

They aren't really "merged together", `first()` generates the function and then you're executing that function with `source$` as the input parameter.

The resulting `output$` is another observable that can be subscribed to.

Comment: Worth noting is that the reason you can write it this way isn't because the rxjs developers designed it to be used that way, but rather a side effect of how observable pipes work. `first()` is meant to be used inside a pipe

Comment: do you know why the operator need to return a function and then take an observable as input ? why we can't do first($observable) directly ?

Answer (score 1):

`first()` is an operation that runs on `(of(1, 2, 3)`. The result will be `1`, since the first value of `1, 2, 3` is `1`, and that's exactly what the `first()` operation does - it takes the first value. This observable is then subscribed to with the chaining on of the `.subscribe()` - and thus, the value `1` is what ends up being printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the intended way of using the first operator, `of(1, 2, 3).pipe(first())` is how it is meant to be used. It works because first returns a function that takes an observable in as a parameter.